# do I need a server distro to run servers?

Tags: server, live-usb, persistence

I'm a LAN admin and I'd like to practice mounting my own servers. I want to start with a DNS and a DHCP server

I want to do it on a Live USB sitck, but there's no Live on Ubuntu Server and there's no Persistent Mode in Debian Live Standard so, the questions are...

- is it possible to install DNS software like Bind9 on a non-server distro?
- can I use any Live distro with persistent mode in order to mount servers and keep them on the USB stick?
- in which case do I need to run a Server distro?

thank you guys!

Comment: You only need to run a server edition if you want to. That said, a server edition takes less space and resources, less time to install and runs faster. Not sure what the advantages of a desktop edition are for server tasks.

Comment: in my case, the advantage would be Live USB Persistent mode so I can keep separated the server from the regular PC. so I'm going for a Desktop version (and maybe boot without a DE). Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off running a server edition on a virtual machine within your usual desktop environment, then access that VM only through SSH to replicate a real world scenario better.
Either type of distro can be configured however you prefer, but the Desktop versions may interfere with background server configurations in unexpected ways.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that (SSH you VM), I'll learn more about it. thank you

Comment: I've found one disadvantage... this is a low on hardware PC so I shouldn't be running a virtual machine, especially if the host is Windows 7 with 1GB of RAM. I figure you mentioned it because I'm interested in keeping the server and the regular PC separated but sadly, this is not an option =/

Comment: Aah then you should maybe look at the LiveUSB option. using something like YUMI - "http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/" you can set persistence with Ubuntu options. I would say it will work fine for educational purposes, and if problems occur then that's also good for education :)

Comment: I know not everybody has the options for that, but seriously consider getting yourself better hardware. Try to get at least 4GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I was also going to suggest you use a VM instead of a live usb, but if you are set on the live usb, you can use the F6 key to add extra command line options and replace the "splash" and "quiet" options with "text" and the desktop live usb will not load the gui, giving you a similar experience to running server edition ( without choosing to install the gui, which you can if you want, but typically is not done on servers ).  The main difference between server and desktop is that desktop comes with the gui installed by default, and uses a gui installer ( server uses a text mode installer ).